# How to drive this 7 segment led?

Tags: driver, 7segmentdisplay

Is there a single IC solution which will act as serial parallel driver for this 7 segment led

[image]

Comment: If you only need to drive a single 7-segment LED, there are 7400 series components for that.

Comment: hmmm.. no, 4 digit, as shown in picture. I am aware of 7400 series.

Comment: Oops, missed that somehow. In which case an SPI enabled chip like wollud suggests is a much better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MAX7219 drives up to eight 7-segment LED and interfaces via SPI to a microcontroller. Is it that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yep, looks exactly what I want!